# How many nodes do we have at each height of d-ary heap?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, asymptotics

I'm trying to prove that we can build a d-ary heap from an array in O(n).

Therefore I'm trying to modify an analysis I have seen in Corman's Book "Introduction to Algorithms" (He proved for d=2) , but I can't figure it out - how many nodes do I have in a specific height i of the heap?

I tried to calculate it for hours but nothing was right.

Actually I need only the # of nodes in height i=1 (because the leafs have zero work on them) and then I can divide it by d for each level.

Would really appreciateyour help (examples would be very helpful as well)

Comment: This might be a better fit on the https://cs.stackexchange.com/ .  Anyway, without knowing the exact algorithm used to make your heap, it makes this question hard to answer.  Your heap could be a perfectly balanced tree or it could be a linked list (the most unbalanced tree).